# Error when trying to dynamically load a React module

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to dynamically include modules but I keep getting the error :

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `HelloWorld`.

This error is located at:
    in HelloWorld (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

This is how I approach it :

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import Components from './ComponentIndex';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const myComponentPath = this.props.myModulePath;
        console.log(">>> Path " + myComponentPath)

        const ComponentToRender = Components[myComponentPath];
        return <ComponentToRender/>
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => HelloWorld);
```

**ComponentIndex.js**

```
let Components = {};

Components['./MyBaseComponent'] = require('./MyBaseComponent').default;

export default Components
```

`console.log(">>> Path : " + this.props.myModulePath)` prints out the intended passed path, for example `./MyBaseComponent`, meaning that it is not empty. The error only comes about whenever I try setting the path from `this.props.myModulePath` as shown above. It however works fine whenever I set it manually `const myComponentPath = "./MyBaseComponent";`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I suspect your component is receiving props at later instance of time after first render, try wrapping that part around conditional statement.

Comment: if its possible, do letme know the solution, kinda next level problem